# How do I specify my target chip as a feature

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, attiny

I would like to program a bare attiny85 with rust. No existing development board, just my own layout. I figured that [attiny-hal](https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal#mcuatmega-hal---mcuattiny-hal-) would be what I need, but I'm stuck at this error:

```
$ cargo check
    Checking attiny-hal v0.1.0 (https://github.com/rahix/avr-hal?rev=4c9c44c314eb061ee20556ef10d45dea36e75ee4#4c9c44c3)
error: This crate requires you to specify your target chip as a feature.
       
           Please select one of the following
       
           * attiny85
           * attiny88
           * attiny167
           * attiny2313
```

I tried these (and many other) settings in `Crate.toml` without success:

```
[package]
name = "avr01"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[features]
attiny85 = []

[dependencies.arduino-hal]
git = "https://github.com/rahix/avr-hal"
rev = "4c9c44c314eb061ee20556ef10d45dea36e75ee4"
features = ["attiny-hal"]
```

How do I select the target chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dependencies you have listed `arduino-hal` but you say you're programming a bare attiny85. You should include the `attiny-hal` crate directly and specify one of those features on the crate for example using this `cargo` command for an `attiny85`:

```bash
cargo add --git "https://github.com/rahix/avr-hal" attiny-hal -F attiny85
```

Which for some reason (I believe it's a bug) currently thinks `attiny85` isn't a feature of `attiny-hal` but you can just specify it
in your `Cargo.toml`. The key for `attiny-hal` should include the required feature:

```ini
[dependencies.attiny-hal]
git = "https://github.com/rahix/avr-hal"
version = "*"
features = ["attiny85"]
```